# How to deploy Administration Area only one a different website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment

I have actually a project which is divided on 3 parts (with 2 areas)

- Website
- Administration (area)
- Moderator (area)

**Website** will be deploy on *www.site.com* without areas
**Administration** and **Moderator** areas will be deploy on *www.adminsite.com* without website

### Why I've do this ?

- Maintain only one project.
- Share code and views

### Question

How I can deploy my application like I want ?
  - Is there a way to deploy only website without areas ?
  - Is there a way to deploy Areas without website ?

### Are there another solutions, I'm listening to you ?

Comment: Do you have to deploy these areas to different domains? You can have the same project with these 3 areas deployed to a same domain and use "Access Control" to make sure that specific users get the access to admin part and so on.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Yes they will be deploy on different domains. One domain is public and the other is internal (for administration and moderation part)

Comment: Then i think you have to deploy the whole thing on all servers and restrict access based on which domain the user is in.

Comment: Yes but I can't do this. I can't put the Administration code on public website ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wainting answers, I consider the only way to do it in the best way is to create another MVC website project and duplicate Views. Thanks for @shwetaOnStack for his attention.